# IE won't set url whereas Chrome will

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<div id="tweeter">
   <div id="tweet1" class="tweet" name="0">
      <div class="tweetimg">
         <img src="/img/none.jpg" id="img" class="img"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="tweetname">Please enable Javascript</div>
      <div class="tweetcontent"></div><div class="tweettime"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="tweet2" class="tweet" name="0">
      <div class="tweetimg">
         <img src="/img/none.jpg" id="imgzwei" class="img"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="tweetname">Please enable Javascript</div><div class="tweetcontent"></div>
      <div class="tweettime"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="tweet3" class="tweet" name="0">
      <div class="tweetimg">
         <img src="/img/none.jpg" id="imgdrei" class="img"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="tweetname">Please enable Javascript</div>
      <div class="tweetcontent"></div>
      <div class="tweettime"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and:

```
var imgone="img/ico1.jpg";
var imgtwo="img/ico2.jpg";
var imgthree="img/ico3.jpg";
jQuery("#img").attr('src',imgone);
jQuery("#imgzwei").attr('src',imgtwo);
jQuery("#imgdrei").attr('src',imgthree);
```

It works fine on Chrome but on IE it can't find `ico2.jpg` and `ico3.jpg`
Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: are u getting an error or images simple do not display?

Comment: Did you use the developer tool in IE to check what's happening? Shortcut key should be F12

Comment: It comes up with the white box and a red X in the middle of it. The console displays nothing.

Comment: What is the `src` in the developer tool then? Has the `src` changed? Did it send any net request to the pics?

Comment: The 'src' does change.

Comment: Is your file **really** `jpg`? Or you rename it manually? for example renaming it from `ico1.ico` to `ico1.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

A bit wierd but this might help (notice leading slash):

```
var imgone="./img/ico1.jpg";
var imgtwo="./img/ico2.jpg";
var imgthree="./img/ico3.jpg";
jQuery("#img").attr('src',imgone);
jQuery("#imgzwei").attr('src',imgtwo);
jQuery("#imgdrei").attr('src',imgthree);
```

Comment: That causes all three of the images to break, and it break on Chrome too.

Comment: @user2422350 the only reason for it not work is the image path to be incorrect. Make sure the file is called `ico1` and has the extension `.jpg`. Check the network tab in developer tools see that the request is sent and notice the server response.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "slightly" different urls in your image tags (starting with "/") as those you're using in your javascript code.

Try it with the missing "/":

```
    var imgone = '/img/ico1.jpg';
```

Comment: That was my first answer. Didn't work for op so I updated mine to `./` instead of `/`. Still didn't work for op though :)

Comment: If the html is NOT working either and the images are in the correct folder - check the access rights...

Answer (score 0):

My IE is ok with your code. which version of IE r u using?

Maybe you can try this way: put 3 img element with style="display:none" in your dom, and their src is those 3 pic. Then change your elem's src to the hidden elem's src.

like this:

HTML:

```
<img src="/img/ico2.jpg" id="hid2" style="display:none"></img>
<img src="/img/ico3.jpg" id="hid3" style="display:none"></img>
```

JS:

```
jQuery("#img").attr('src',$('#hid2').attr('src'));
jQuery("#imgzwei").attr('src',$('#hid2').attr('src'));
```

Comment: I am currently using IE9-We are doing this for an assignment at school so my teacher won't update.